# basic php form not working

Tags: php, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
        </head>
    <body>
    <?php

        $name; 
        $college;
        if(empty($_POST["name"])){
            $nameerr="NAME IS REQUIRED";
        }
        else{
            $name=$_POST["name"];
        }
        $course=$_POST["course"];
        if(empty($_POST["college"])){
            $collegeerr="NAME OF COLLEGE IS REQUIRED";
        }else{
            $college=$_POST["college"];
        }
        $email=$_POST["email"];
        $abc=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','generalinfo') or die('ERROR:COULD NOT          CONNECT TO DATABASE');
        $query="INSERT INTO studentinfo VALUES ('$name','$course','$college','$email')";
        $final=mysqli_query($abc,$query) or die('ERROR ENTERING THE DATA IN DATABASE');
        mysqli_close($abc);
        echo'THANKYOU FOR SUBMITTING THE FORM';

    ?>
    <div id="b">
        <form action=""  method="post">
            <label for="name"><div id="a">name</div></label>
            <input type="text" name="name"></br>
            <div id="c"><?php echo $nameerr; ?></div>
            <label for="course"><div id="a">course</div></label>
            <input type="text" name="course"></br>
            <label for="email"><div id="a">email</div></label>
            <input type="text" name="email"></br>
            <label for="college"><div id="a">college</div></label>
            <input type="text" name="college"></br>
            <div id="d"><?php echo $collegeerr; ?></div>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="sub"></br>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

After i press the submit button nothing happens..no error message comes up if i don't fill out the name or college  field..also the filled the out information is not recieved in the database ...any kind of help will be appreciated ..thanks in advance

Comment: in your `action=""` give path of page having PHP code

Comment: Lines like `$name;` don't do anything, it should be `echo $name;`.

Comment: make sure you have display error enable?

Answer (score 0):

you should add an action

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
```

And then include the form.php in you website's folder.

Comment: It looks like he's using the same script to display and process the form. That's the default if you leave the action empty.

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue your having rather than the `action=""` if it is all on the same page is that your query isn't saying where you want each value to go

```
$query="INSERT INTO studentinfo (name, course, college, email) VALUES ('$name','$course','$college','$email')";
```

try changing your query to that but make sure the field names are correct i just guessed using your variables

Comment: If you leave out the list of columns, it uses the columns from the table definition.

Comment: If this were the problem, it would execute the `or die()` code.

Answer (score 0):

You should first check that the $_POST is empty or not.Then you should save the data.So, use thid code:

```
 <?php
  $collegeerr = $nameerr = '';
  if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
            $name = ''; 
            $college = '';
            if(empty($_POST["name"])){
                $nameerr="NAME IS REQUIRED";
            }
            else{
                $name=$_POST["name"];
            }
            $course=$_POST["course"];
            if(empty($_POST["college"])){
                $collegeerr="NAME OF COLLEGE IS REQUIRED";
            }else{
                $college=$_POST["college"];
            }
            $email=$_POST["email"];
            $abc=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','generalinfo') or die('ERROR:COULD NOT          CONNECT TO DATABASE');
            $query="INSERT INTO studentinfo(name, course, college, email) VALUES ('$name','$course','$college','$email')";
            $final=mysqli_query($abc,$query) or die('ERROR ENTERING THE DATA IN DATABASE');
            mysqli_close($abc);
            echo'THANKYOU FOR SUBMITTING THE FORM';
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of issues with this code.

you can do the following things to get it resolved

#### 1. Wrap the post specific code inside a condition

You are executing the post handling code block even when the page is not posted. the code for handling post action has to be wrapped under an if condition which checks if the POST array is empy or not

#### 2. Show the error variables only when they are set

Error vraibales used in side the form like `$nameerr` and `$collegeerr` are not set when the page is not posted. So you have to show them only when they are set. wrap them under a `if(isset())` condition.

#### 3. Remove unwanted lines which serve no purpose

As barmer says in the comments, lines like `$name;$college;` are of no use. They doesnt serve the purpose of variable declarations. You can remove them.

#### 4. Turn error_reporting on

You are not seeing these errors because you might have turned your error reporting off in php.ini. Its better to turn it on as it helps a lot in debugging the code. You can do this by going to php.ini and setting `display_errors` property on.

### code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
        </head>
    <body>
    <?php       
        if(!empty($_POST)) {
        
            if(empty($_POST["name"])){
                $nameerr="NAME IS REQUIRED";
            }
            else{
                $name=$_POST["name"];
            }
            $course=$_POST["course"];
            if(empty($_POST["college"])){
                $collegeerr="NAME OF COLLEGE IS REQUIRED";
            }else{
                $college=$_POST["college"];
            }
            if(!isset($nameerr) && !isset($collegeerr)){
                $email=$_POST["email"];
                $abc=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test') or die('ERROR:COULD NOT          CONNECT TO DATABASE');
                $query="INSERT INTO studentinfo VALUES ('$name','$course','$college','$email')";
                $final=mysqli_query($abc,$query) or die('ERROR ENTERING THE DATA IN DATABASE');
                mysqli_close($abc);
                echo 'THANKYOU FOR SUBMITTING THE FORM';
            }
        }
    ?>
    <div id="b">
        <form action=""  method="post">
            <label for="name"><div id="a">name</div></label>
            <input type="text" name="name"></br>
            <div id="c"><?php if(isset($nameerr)) echo $nameerr; ?></div>
            <label for="course"><div id="a">course</div></label>
            <input type="text" name="course"></br>
            <label for="email"><div id="a">email</div></label>
            <input type="text" name="email"></br>
            <label for="college"><div id="a">college</div></label>
            <input type="text" name="college"></br>
            <div id="d"><?php if(isset($collegeerr)) echo $collegeerr; ?></div>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="sub"></br>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, single quotes should be used if there's no variable inside the text or if it's the name of the POST variable.